# Is there a specific scenario of a hash table that isn't full yet an insertion can't occur?

Tags: algorithm, hash, logic, hashtable

What I mean to ask is for a hash-table following the standard size of a prime number, is it possible to have some scenario (of inserted keys) where no further insertion of a given element is possible even though there's some empty slots? What kind of hash-function would achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

So, most hash functions allow for collisions ("Hash Collisions" is the phrase you should google to understand this better, by the way.) Collisions are handled by having a secondary data structure, like a list, to store all of the values inserted at keys with the same hash.

Because these data structures can generally store arbitrarily many elements, you will always be able to insert into the hash table, but the performance will get worse and worse, approaching the performance of the backing data structure.

If you do not have a backing data structure, then you can be unable to insert as soon as two things get added to the same position. Since a good hash function distributes things evenly and effectively randomly, this would happen pretty quickly (see "The Birthday Problem").

Comment: Collisions can be handled by other strategies.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing for a different one.

Comment: Thanks, the birthday problem was great to research regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

There are failure-to-insert scenarios for some but not all hash table implementations.

For example, [*closed hashing* aka *open addressing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) implementations use some logic to create a sequence of buckets in which they'll *"probe"* for values not found at the hashed-to bucket due to collisions.  In the real world, sometimes the sequence-creation is pretty basic, for example:

- the programmer might have hard-coded N prime numbers, thinking the odds of adding in each of those in turn and still not finding an empty bucket are low (but a malicious user who knows the hash table design may be able to calculate values to make the table fail, or it may simply be so full that the odds are no longer good, or - while emptier - a statistical freak event)
- the programmer might have done something like picked a prime number they liked - say 13903 - to add to the last-probed bucket each time until a free one is found, but if the table size happens to be 13903 too it'll keep checking the same bucket.

Still, there are probing approaches such as [*linear probing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) that guarantee to try all buckets (unless the implementation goes out of its way to put a limit on retries).  It has some other "issues" though, and won't always be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If a hash table is implemented using [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) instead of [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining), then it is a good idea to leave at least 1 slot empty to simplify the algorithm.

In open addressing when we are trying to find an element, we first compute the hash index i, then check the table at indexes {i, i + 1, i + 2, ... N - 1, (wrapping around) 0, 1, 2, ...}, until we either find the element we want or hit an empty slot. You can see that in this algorithm, if no slot is empty but the element can't be found, then the search would loop forever.

However, I should emphasize that enforcing merely *simplifies* the search algorithm. Because alternatively, the search algorithm can remember the starting index i, and halt the search if the entire table has been scanned and it lands back at index i.